how to post JSON data to a soap service
I sent this JSON data to a soap service and it returns Runtime Type Mismatch error.
{
    "username":"blabla",
    "password":"blabla"
}

I need to send this JSON data to the soap service. How can I do that ?

You need to convert this json  dato into XML format that the SOAP service can understand and then send the XML formatted data to SOAP services.

Is there any way to auto convert this json to xml data ?

Which language/framework you are using? Depending upon language/framework you use, the conversion from json to xml will take place

I am using Java language and trying to reach another soa server with json payload.
